# Get User IP Address in client screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm using lightswitch 2013 VB and I need to read the user ip address in execute function of a button on a screen , I am not able to use the below code

```
                 Dim context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current()
                MyIPAddress = context.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Please Advise.

Note: I'm using desktop client and the code written in the client project

Comment: Are you running a HTML 5 or Desktop client?  Is this code in the Server project or in the client project?

Answer (score 1):

System.Web is not available in the sandbox for a SilverLight desktop client.  System.Net might give you something more helpful, but ultimately, I suspect the sandbox will prevent you from getting anything useful back.